# Back/forward buttons Firefox 4

Tags: windows-xp

I have just loaded Firefox 4 and cannot find the back/forward buttons (arrows?).  I cannot move from page to page.  I have to use another browser to access programs with multiple pages.

Answer (score 2):

On the default skin they are to the left of the address box:

[image: back/forward buttons]

You need to have navigated between pages for them to be enabled of course.